# Change Dynamically the Current Connection - Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to change the current connection dynamically in symfony?

I ask this because I will only know what the database to use when the user logs in to your account.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony makes each DBAL connection a separate service in the DI container. The default one is always called `database_connection` and is usually just an alias to `doctrine.dbal.admin_connection`.

Then if you have other connections they're automatically added. For example I have `default` and `admin` connections so Symfony created:

```
doctrine.dbal.admin_connection
doctrine.dbal.default_connection
```

You can use `app/console debug:container | grep "DBAL\\\\Connection"` in console to dump all registered connections.

Comment: I have explained me wrong.What I wonder is if I can create a new connection when you receive the parameters from another server and get the same connection as default

Comment: You can override a service using `set()` method on `service_container`. See https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/3.1/Container.php#L162. However I don't think this is a good idea because you can't know what other services have already registered that service as dependency and it might broke somewhere unexpectedly.